# How to convert a Json string to List in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

In web service i am try to convert a jzonString to a list.

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "Fname": "Testing",
    "S1": "Content1",
    "S2": "Content2",
    "S3": "Content3"
}
```

```
[WebMethod]
        public int Create(string Detils, string Companyid)
        {
            try
            {

                dynamic ScheduleShift = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(Detils);
                \\ i need to set data to list or to an object

                InvDetails objDetails = new InvDetails();
                List<InvDetails> lstDetails = new List<InvDetails>();

                return objDetails.CreateInvDetails(objDetils);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Abort Transaction
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Created another library file to declare the object and to insert into db

```
 public class Inventory
    {
        CommonExecDAL CommonExecDAL = new CommonExecDAL();
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string S1 { get; set; }
        public string S2 { get; set; }
        public string S3 { get; set; }
        public int intCompanyId { get; set; }


        public int CreateInvComputer(InvDetails objInvDetails)
        {

            SqlParameter[] arParms = new SqlParameter[6];
            .........

        }
    }
```

Comment: NewtonSoft.Json is the library you should be using. There tons of examples available on internet about how to use it for Jain serialization and deserialization.

Comment: you can deserialize a JSON **array** into a list. But your JSON is a single object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create a class :
You can use `JObject.Parse()` method for deserializing dynamically.

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;  //Need to add refference//                                                                        
 JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(Detils);                                                                          
objDetails.name = (string)jObject.SelectToken("name");

Answer (score 0):

As @SirRufo said, you can deserialize a JSON array into a list. but your JSON string in the sample is a single object!

Anyway, you deserialize JSON string to object with the use [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

First, you have a class for `Deserialize` :

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize JSON string to C# class :

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add reference to `System.Web.Extensions` ,(built in dll on .NET 4+) :

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObj =jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

Comment: It worked but return key and value based array. i tried to assign the value to my object  objDetails.name  = jsonObj[0].value but it got error

Comment: @Roshmi Try to access it like jsonObj[“yourKey”]